# How to correct addition of parentheses to not use parentheses unnecessarily python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, prefix, infix-notation

I am making a program which converting Prefix to Infix and I have a problem with putting brackets to expression. 
For converting, I use classic stack algorithm. Here is my function for brackits.

1. Input:

   ```
   //+86 16 67/*/31 53 85 15
   ```
2. My output:

   ```
   ((86+16)/67)/(((31/53)*85)/15)
   ```
3. Expecting output :

   ```
   (86+16)/67/(31/53*85/15)
   ```

> ```
> def breckets(operand1, operand2, operace):
> res = ""
> if (operand1.isdigit()) and (operand2.isdigit()):
>     res = operand1 + operace + operand2
> elif (operand1.isdigit()) and (not operand2.isdigit()):
>     if operace == "+":
>         res = operand1 + operace + operand2
>     else:
>         res = operand1 + operace + "(" + operand2 + ")"
> elif (not operand1.isdigit()) and (operand2.isdigit()):
>     if prior(operace) != 0:
>         res = "(" + operand1 + ")" + operace + operand2
>     else:
>         res = operand1 + operace + operand2
> else:
>     res = "(" + operand1 + ")" + operace + "(" + operand2 + ")"
> return res
> ```

```
def prior(a):
    prior = None
    if a in "+-":
        prior = 0
    elif a in "*/":
        prior = 1
    elif a in "^":
        prior = 2
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")
        exit()
    return prior
```

But I must not use parentheses unnecessarily, can anybody advice me something please?

Comment: Please add the call to the functions with some input data, the output you got with your code and the expected output.

Comment: Is the return value of the function going to be used as operand in anther brackets function? Should the return value be in always with brackets outside,except both operands are number?

Comment: Are you trying to get something like: (E^F), D, /  >>> (D/(E^F)) ?

Comment: @ShengZhuang no, I need to put bracket only if it is necessary. So it should be without outside brackets

Comment: @ShengZhuang well try to put it in to calculator ...  without breckets it has wrong answer )

Answer (score 0):

The code below can get what you expect. but I am not sure if the algorithm is right as I am not familiar with the data structure.

I use a basic function to sort the list several times, instead of sorting the list strictly from right to left, you can change some lines to break the while loop to make it so if that is what you want.

Anyway hope this can help you somehow.

```
operators = "+-*/^"
# presume the input is a finely spaced str that can be splitted into a proper list
# ipt = "/ * + 86 16 67 / * / + 31 53 85 15 / / 33 45 74"  # for testing
ipt = "/ / + 86 16 67 / * / 31 53 85 15"  
ip = ipt.split()


def sorting(lst):
    res = []
    i = len(lst)-1  # check list items from right to left
    while i >= 0:
        if i >= 3:
            if lst[i-2] in operators:
                # check if the operator is followed by two numbers
                if lst[i-1] not in operators and lst[i] not in operators: 
                    # check if the operator is + | -, the result should be in parentheses
                    if lst[i-2] in "+-":
                        res.append("(" + lst[i-1] + lst[i-2] + lst[i] + ")")
                        i -=3
                        continue
                    # if the operator is following another operator, the result shouldn't be in parentheses
                    if lst[i-3] in operators:
                        res.append(lst[i-1] + lst[i-2] + lst[i])
                        i -=3
                        continue
                    # if the operator is following a number, the result shouldn be in parentheses
                    else:
                        res.append("(" + lst[i-1] + lst[i-2] + lst[i] + ")")
                        i -= 3
                        continue
        # this is to check the first item of the list is an operator and followed by two numbers
        elif i == 2:
            if lst[i-2] in operators:
                if lst[i-1] not in operators and lst[i] not in operators:
                    res.append(lst[i-1] + lst[i-2] + lst[i])
                    i -=3
                    continue
        res.append(lst[i])
        i -= 1
    # as all items are appending to the new list, so the positions are totally reversed
    return list(reversed(res))

def no_more_operators(lst):
    # to check if the lst is sortable
    # one scenario is there are exccesive numbers, but no operators
    # the current function can only check if any operators is in the list
    for op in operators:
        if op in lst:
            return False
    return True

def no_more_numbers(lst):
    # to check if the lst is sortable
    # one scenario is there are exccesive operators, but no numbers
    # the current function can only check if any number is in the list
    for i in lst:
        if i.isnumeric():
            return False
    return True

# keep sorting the list until there is no more numbers or n0 more operators
while not no_more_numbers(ip) or not no_more_operators(ip):
    ip = sorting(ip)
    print(ip)
```

output:

```
['/', '/', '(86+16)', '67', '/', '*', '31/53', '85', '15']
['/', '(86+16)/67', '/', '31/53*85', '15']
['/', '(86+16)/67', '(31/53*85/15)']
['(86+16)/67/(31/53*85/15)']
```

Comment: Well that is better than my solution but (its definatly shorter than my code), but it isnt work for examples like this 
input : /49-/34 74-17/69 78
output  '49/(34/74-(17-(69/78)))'
expected output : 49/(34/74-(17-69/78))